# How to store multiple columns of a csv dataset in a single variable in java so that the variable can be used as input feature for ml model

Tags: java, python

```
    I have done this in python. Here is my python code:
    Here X is the input variable in which I stored all the 
    input columns of csv file and y is the target variable.

          dataset=pandas.read_csv("newone.csv")
          features = [0,1,4,5,6,7]
          X =dataset.iloc[:,features]
          y =dataset.iloc[:,2]
    How can I do this in java?
```

Here is my java code in which I read the csv file but 
I am able to store only one column value of the csv in a variable.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:/Users/N/Desktop/newone.csv"));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("Enounter", "Relation", "Event", "Tag","Encounter_no", "Diagonosis", "User_Id", "Client_Id").withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                encntr=csvRecord.get("Encounter");
      }
    }


    ----------
```

Comment: you may need to use POI library to read excel/CSV files.
which will provide inbuilt functions to read cell at a particular location. add a screenshot of csv data to let us better understand how you are reading the cells in python

Comment: Can you suggest me some reference link for POI library regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [MyKong's code on how to read CSV files in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/). Something like the following snippet below (heavily borrowed from MyKong's better version):

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] valuesFromLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    String secondValue = valuesFromLine[1];
    // do something with second value
}
```

Comment: I am able to read the csv I have updated my code. please take a look.

Comment: Instead of putting your fields into a single variable, consider using the `HashMap` datastructure, calling the `put` method to add them and the corresponding `get` method to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Download these jar https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.15 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.15
and add them to your build path

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        //specify your file path
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.xlsx");

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //to fetch sheet
         XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

         // for iterating through rows
        for(int c=0;c<=sheet.getLastRowNum();c++)
        {
            // for iterating through columns
            Row rows = sheet.getRow(c);
            for(int b=0;b<=rows.getLastCellNum();b++)
            {   
                Cell cells=rows.getCell(b);
                //to read cell value as string
                String comp=cells.getStringCellValue(); 

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is POI is compatible with jdk 8 because the latest version of POI is compatible with jdk 6 only.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html as per source, it would support jdk 6 and later versions too

Comment: POI 4.0 will support jdk 8 and it is not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

**This depends entirely on what the relationship between your columns is like.** It is impossible to answer this question in a general manner as this changes from dataset to dataset and even from algorithm to algorithm, but here are a few approaches you might like to try:

- Use [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to identify if there any variables in your desired tuple of columns you can omit because they contribute very little to the row class variable.
- Use [Feature Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) to reduce the dimensionality of your dataset by bundling together related properties (this *does not* work as a blanket solution - indeed, nothing in ML ever does. Try it before you commit to it).
- If the columns you'd like to unite are numerical, you may want to think of an algorithm to join them in a [unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) way, or a way which makes sense. If they are categorical, a sparse [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) bit vector may help you.

Comment: I don't want to unite the columns here I just want to divide the dataset in input data and ouput data(target label) which I did in my python code.